# how to get the sprite attached to a box2d body if i knew the body?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

After collision detection I can get the bodies that collided, but how can I get the sprites attached to these bodies so I can remove them from the scene also?

For example if I had a body (player) this body collided with another body (enemy), I can get which bodies collide from the contact listener like this:

```
pContact.getFixtureA().getBody()
pContact.getFixtureB().getBody()
```

So if we assume that we have a lot of enemies how can I get the exact sprite attached to each one of the bodies so I can remove them?

Answer (score 4):

disclaimer: My experience is with Cocos2d/Box2D in iOS, but should be similar in Android.

Typically, when using Box2D bodies and sprites you set the UserData property of the Body Definition with the sprite. Example:

setting userData:

```
bodyDef.UserData = sprite;
```

retrieving sprite after contact:

```
enemySprite = pContact.getFixtureA().getBody().GetUserData()
```

Comment: but i am already using the user data to store a string to use it to detect which two bodies collided in collision detection, so if i use the user data to store the sprite how can i know which bodies collided?

Comment: Well, you could store both things. Nothing stops you from creating a class with a sprite (tipically inheriting from it) with an extra property for your custom string.

Answer (score 2):

You should have an `Enemy` class, that has its `Body` and `Sprite`. If you have a body that had a contact with an another body, you can iterate over the list of your `Enemy` objects to find whose body was that by simply comparing them. Then you can easily get this `Enemy` object's sprite. Hope I've explained my idea clear enough.

Comment: i understand your idea but can you give me a sample code to how to make such class, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

After read [this](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/alternative-way-of-getting-sprite-from-body-t11581.html) thread on AndEngine forums, this is my solution:

Create a new "UserData" class:

```
public class UserData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String mString;
    Object mObject;

    public UserData(){}

    public UserData(String string, Object object) {
        this.mString = string;
        this.mObject = object;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return mString;
    }

    public Object getObject() {
        return mObject;
    }
}
```

Set the UserData of **all** your `body`s with the UserData class:

```
body.setUserData(new UserData("enemy", CustomSprite));
```

Then you can detect the collision and get your CustomSprite:

```
if (((UserData) x1.getBody().getUserData()).getString().equals("enemy") && ((UserData) x2.getBody().getUserData()).getString().equals("bullet")) {
    CustomSprite myEnemySprite = (CustomSprite) ((UserData) x1.getBody().getUserData()).getObject();
    myEnemySprite.die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enemy.setUserData(new Object[]{"enemy",enemySprite/*,... And other objects as user data if you wish */})
```

And while checking:

```
final Object[] x1 = (Object[]) contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData();
final Object[] x2 = (Object[]) contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData();
```

Doing something:

```
if(x1[0].equals("This is the tag for the enemy"))
x2[1].playerhascollidedwithyouandyouhavetodosomething();
```